# Why is this a Callout loop?

Tags: calloutexception

When a customer buys my app from AppExchange, Salesforce creates a new Lead in my Partner Business Org (PBO), with lead source set to "Package Install". When that happens, I have written automation to make a callout to my API provider (Twilio), create a subAccount, return the credentials.

When those credentials are received, I encode them into a license key and email it to the customer. I also save these credentials to custom object records on my PBO. This should all happen by the time they finish their download/install.

I can run all of this successfully using Execute Anonymous, or by creating the Lead myself, no errors. However, it won't run automatically (triggered by a Process that watching for new Leads with the right Lead Source, which calls invokable apex.) The Process works, the code gets called, but it hits the callout to Twilio and gives me this error:

```
Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 0056A000002Cfbr/00D6A0000039I9T 

Failed to invoke future method 'private static void makeTwilioSubaccount(String, String, String)' on class 'Registration' for job id '7076A00003jZ9VH' 

caused by: System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed 

Class.TwilioClient.request: line 428, column 1 
Class.TwilioClient.safeRequest: line 579, column 1 
Class.TwilioResource.TwilioListResource.createInstance: line 408, column 1 
Class.TwilioAccountList.create: line 64, column 1 
Class.Registration.makeTwilioSubaccount: line 91, column 1
```

Reading [the docs on Callout loop](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232321&type=1). I'm thinking that the user context when this is initiated by the AppExchange org creating the lead is that AppExchange Org. And this callout is coming from my PBO. Does that make this a callout loop?

Assuming that's the issue, how can I mask the user context? If I initiate it from a Flow, does the user context change to the user who Runs the Flow?

Here's the class:

```
global class Registration {

@InvocableMethod(label='Lead to License')
global static void processLead(List<RegistrationRequest> requests){
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
    for (RegistrationRequest request : requests){
        leads.add(request.Lead);
    }
    routeIntallationLeads(leads);

}  

private static void routeIntallationLeads(List<Lead> leads)
{
    List<Lead> leadsNeedingPta = new List<Lead>();
    for(Lead lead : leads){
        // check for ProtonTextAccount__c with this lead's email address AND company
        List<ProtonTextAccount__c> ptaList = [SELECT Id, Email__c
                                    FROM ProtonTextAccount__c
                                    WHERE Email__c = :lead.Email AND Company__c = :lead.Company
                                    LIMIT 1];
        if (ptaList.isEmpty()) {// no PTA with this lead's email address AND company
            leadsNeedingPta.add(lead);
        }else {// PTA already exists with this Lead's email, fire Reinstallation platform event
            Registration.fireReinstallation(ptaList[0].id);
        }
    }
    if (!leadsNeedingPta.isEmpty()) {// if there are any leadsNeedingPta...
        Registration.createTwilioSubaccounts(leadsNeedingPta);
    }
}

public static void createTwilioSubaccounts(List<Lead> leads){  
    for(Lead lead : leads){
        makeTwilioSubaccount(accountName, lead.Id, lead.Email);
    }
}


@future (callout=true)
private static void makeTwilioSubaccount(String accountName, String leadId, String Email){
    //licenseId is not needed, just passed through to the platform event
    Credential__mdt p7gMaster = [SELECT [credential fields] 
                                       FROM Credential__mdt 
                                       WHERE AccountName__c = [masterCreds]
                                       LIMIT 1];
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(p7gMaster.creds1__c, p7gMaster.creds2__c);
    Map<String, String> properties = new Map<String,String>{'FriendlyName' => accountName};
   // THIS NEXT LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS -- THE ACTUAL CALLOUT
    TwilioAccount subAccount = client.getAccounts().create(properties); 

    Registration.fireTwilioSubaccountCreated(subAccount, leadId, Email);
}

private static void fireTwilioSubaccountCreated(TwilioAccount subAccount, String leadId, String Email)
{
    TwilioSubaccountCreated__e tsc = new TwilioSubaccountCreated__e();
    [load up the fields of the platform event, then...]
    Database.SaveResult eventResult = EventBus.publish(tsc);
    if(eventResult.isSuccess()){
        System.debug('Successfully published TwilioSubaccountCreated event.');
    } else {
        for(Database.Error error : eventResult.getErrors()){
            System.debug('TwilioSubaccountCreated event error: ' + error.getStatusCode() + ' | ' + error.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private static void fireReinstallation(String PtaId) {
   [another platform event code]
}


private static void insertPtas(List<ProtonTextAccount__c> ptaList)
{
   [creates internal record of the subaccount]
}
```

}

UPDATED:
I've now created a Flow that accepts the Lead as input, then calls the invocable Apex, passing on that Lead. In my Process, I changed from calling the Apex, to calling the Flow that calls the Apex. It works when I create my own lead, so I know it's wired up correctly. I won't be able to test it until I get another app download and AppExchange creates the Lead.

Comment: one could also consider using Platform Events which will decouple the originating transaction from the callout to send the license key

Comment: @cropredy, good idea. So instead of calling makeTwilioSubaccount, fire a platform event with the Lead attached, put a trigger on the platform event that makes the callout. If my current strategy of putting it in a flow doesn't work, that's what I'll try. Thanks!  I'll post an answer here once I find out if the Flow thing works.

Comment: the platform event gives you replay options (from the Lead) if the license key issuance fails. Just publish a new platform event from a simple button on the Lead detail page